# Despite rpath is set, one shared library is not found

Tags: linux, gcc, clang, ldd, rpath

ldd fails to find a dll that is present in the rpath definition. Some others libraries are found (check /./../lib/*)

Here the output of ldd (we can see that 2 dlls are found in ../lib, but not libexpat.so.0):

```
root@hyperstream:/DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-Default/bin# ldd ./ade_admin
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeb9796000)
libadeversion.so =>  /DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-efault/bin/./../lib/libadeversion.so
(0x00007f31abaef000)
libuuid.so.1 =>    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f31ab8ca000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(0x00007f31ab6ac000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-Default/bin/**./../lib/libaprutil-1.so.0**
(0x00007f31ab58c000)
libapr-1.so.0 =>  /DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-Default/bin/**./../lib/libapr-1.so.0**
(0x00007f31ab460000)
libavahi-client.so.3 =>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007f31ab24d000)
libavahi-common.so.3 =>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007f31ab041000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f31aae3d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(0x00007f31aaab5000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f31aa7ac000)
libgcc_s.so.1 =>    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f31aa595000)
libc.so.6 =>    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f31aa1cc000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560d30a76000)     
**libexpat.so.0 =>   not found**    
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
(0x00007f31a9fc4000) [...]

root@hyperstream:/DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-Default/bin# file ../lib/libexpat.so.0
../lib/libexpat.so.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared
object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,
BuildID[sha1]=762de704943d03033d01a9725216d6b05d0740f5, not stripped
```

Here the rpath:

```
root@hyperstream:/DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-Default/bin#
readelf -d ade_admin | grep 'R.*PATH' 16: 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)
Library runpath: **[${ORIGIN}/../lib]**
```

Now the killer fact: It works with clang 3.8, but fails with gcc 6.3 (ubuntu 16.10)

Obviously adding an LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib make it works again, but the goal of rpath was to avoid to set it

```
root@hyperstream:/DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-Default/bin# export **LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib** 
root@hyperstream:/DT/local/ADE-trunk4/build-ADE-Desktop-Default/bin# ldd ./ade_admin
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffea23b6000)
libadeversion.so => ../lib/libadeversion.so (0x00007f78c6474000)     
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f78c624f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f78c6031000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => ../lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007f78c5f11000)
libapr-1.so.0 => ../lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007f78c5de5000)   
libavahi-client.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3 (0x00007f78c5bd2000)
libavahi-common.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3 (0x00007f78c59c6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f78c57c2000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f78c543a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f78c5131000)    
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f78c4f1a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f78c4b51000)    
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559fdceab000)
libexpat.so.0 => .**./lib/libexpat.so.0** (0x00007f78c492a000)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Just so you know, a "DLL" is the _Windows-specific_ name for a shared library. In Linux/Unix land, we just call them "shared libraries" or "SOs" (pronounced "ess ohs"). Seeing "RPATH" and "DLL" in the same sentence is odd because Windows doesn't have an RPATH equivalent.

Comment: @AlexReinking on Linux shared libraries are often called [DSOs (Dynamic Shared Objects)](https://akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). And DLLs are most certainly not shared objects. They share part of the purpose (making functions available) but have _quite_ considerably different semantics. And depending on how you look at it Windows _does_ have equivalents to RPATH. Be it in your own delay-loading handler or DLL search paths etc. But the use of DLL is indeed odd. The easiest is to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just find the explanation: clang put in the [NEEDED] section of the elf binary ALL libraries (even libraries not explicitely included by myself, but referenced by the [NEEDED] section of the library that I include

example from gcc:

```
readelf -d my_prog

Dynamic section at offset 0x9cb548 contains 46 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libadeversion.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libuuid.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsqlite3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaprutil-1.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libapr-1.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libavahi-client.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libavahi-common.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaio.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_adm64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_dict64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_rdm64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_dbr64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [${ORIGIN}/../lib/:$ORIGIN/../lib/:../lib/]
```

from clang:

```
readelf -d my_prog

Dynamic section at offset 0xa7bae8 contains 54 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libadeversion.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libuuid.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsqlite3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaprutil-1.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libexpat.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libapr-1.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libavahi-client.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libavahi-common.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaio.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_adm64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_dict64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_rdm64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_rpc64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_sql64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_rdbc64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_rm64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_ncp64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_cmp64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_repfltr64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_expat64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_cncp64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [lib_dbr64.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [${ORIGIN}/../lib/:$ORIGIN/../lib/:../lib/]
```

And one dll include the missing one libexpat:

```
readelf -d ../lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 

Dynamic section at offset 0x1e698 contains 29 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: **[libexpat.so.0]**
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libapr-1.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libuuid.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libaprutil-1.so.0]
```

but RUNPATH is only used by the binary not by the dll (that can have is own RUNPATH too).

2 solutions:
- add a RUNPATH in libaprutil-1.so.0 to force to include library from "."
- add explicitely all missing dll in my build

Hope it help

Comment: Even `clang` does not do this on its own. Beside you don't specify what linker you used when building (with either compiler). In the BFD linker you'd have use `--no-as-needed` to change the default behavior where the linker throws out library references not needed because all other libraries satisfy the "needed symbols".